# PHP regex, incorrect escaping of html causing problem

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use `(.+?)` to isolate the words "I. NEED. ISOLATION" in the source below:

```
<strong>Label:</strong></font></td>
    <td valign="top" width="82%"> <font face="Arial" size="2"> 
      I. NEED. ISOLATION  </font> </td>
```

using `(.+?)`, I could do this:

```
$regex = '/stuff before(.+?)stuff after/';
```

and for this html, that would be:

```
$regex = '/<strong>Label:</strong></font></td>
    <td valign="top" width="82%"> <font face="Arial" size="2"> 
      (.+?)  </font> </td>/';
```

but it's choking up on it because of incorrect escaping. I'm not great in PHP. Can someone please advise which characters I should also escape based on html that looks like this?

```
<strong>Label:</strong></font></td>
    <td valign="top" width="82%"> <font face="Arial" size="2"> 
      I. NEED. ISOLATION  </font> </td>
```

**Note that I'm not trying to design a regex pattern. I already have the pattern nailed down with `(.+?)`, just need to know how to correctly escape the html so that php doesn't choke up on it.**

Answer (score 3):

See [this previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

That said, the escaping issue is due to the `/` characters within, which are confusing the regex parser since you're using `/`es already to delimit the regex.

Comment: That's a lot of info, but I'm trying to use `(.+?)` to isolate the string I need, so I'm not really trying to match all those patterns. Just trying to figure out what should be escaped and how. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, we realize that (and I mentioned what you need to escape in my answer). However, we're also giving you a helpful suggestion that you may want to consider alternatives to regex - it can often avoid hassles in the future if you need to expand beyond a limited case.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should really not use regular expressions to try to "parse" HTML -- which is not quite regular.

Going with something like [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and some XPath query is generally a much better solution.

But, if you really want to go with a regex *(and it seems you do, judging from your comments to other answers)*, I suppose you should not use `/` as [regex delimiter][2] : there are too many slashed in HTML already -- it'll be an escaping hell, as you already noticed.

For instance, you could use a `#` as regex delimiter :

```
$str = <<<STR
<strong>Label:</strong></font></td>
    <td valign="top" width="82%"> <font face="Arial" size="2"> 
      I. NEED. ISOLATION  </font> </td>
STR;
$regex = '#<strong>Label:</strong></font></td>
    <td valign="top" width="82%"> <font face="Arial" size="2"> 
      (.+?)  </font> </td>#';
if (preg_match($regex, $str, $m)) {
  var_dump($m[1]);
}
```

Will get you :

```
string 'I. NEED. ISOLATION' (length=18)
```

Note the only thing I changed compared to your proposed code is the regex delimiter ;-)

And, using a character that's not present in the HTML string, I don't have anything to escape -- especially, I don't have to escape all the `/`s -- which means the regex is far more easy to both write, read, and understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using [PCRE regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php), you need to escape the [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) inside the regular expression (in your case the `/`):

```
'/<strong>Label:<\/strong><\/font><\/td>
<td valign="top" width="82%"> <font face="Arial" size="2"> 
  (.+?)  <\/font> <\/td>/'
```

But probably more important: Regular expressions are not suitable for parsing HTML. Better use a proper HTML parser like the one provided by [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) and query it with [DOMXPath](http://php.net/domxpath).

Answer (score 0):

```
$str=<<<EOF
<strong>Label:</strong></font></td>
    <td valign="top" width="82%"> <font face="Arial" size="2">
      I. NEED. ISOLATION  </font> </td>
EOF;

$s = explode("</font>",$str);
foreach($s as $k=>$v){
    if(strpos($v,'<font face="Arial" size="2">')){
        $t=explode('<font face="Arial" size="2">',$v);
        print trim($t[1])."\n";
    }
}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
I. NEED. ISOLATION
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a funciton that does that for you. It's named **preg_quote** http://pl2.php.net/preg_quote

```
$regex = '/'.preg_quote('<strong>Label:</strong></font></td>
<td valign="top" width="82%"> <font face="Arial" size="2"> 
  ').'(.+?)'.preg_quote('  </font> </td>).'/';
```

You should also be careful with case sensitivity and line breaks. I often tend to add flags to my regexps to deal with it so they look like `/(.+?)/is`

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, there's nothing in that string that has special meaning in a regex (except the `(.+?)`, of course).  The only reason the `/` is causing a problem is because you're using it as the regex delimiter.  You just need to choose a different delimiter, like `~` for example:

```
$regex = '~<strong>Label:</strong></font></td>
    <td valign="top" width="82%"> <font face="Arial" size="2"> 
      (.+?)  </font> </td>~';
```